# Make 2 divs move in inverse directions

Tags: jquery, html, css

Sorry for such a dummy question of mine I think. Please help me if someone know the way to make the div have animation up and down when scrolling like this: http://velvethammer.net/

You can see near the footer of the site, it has 2 sections which contain 2 images each (one bigger and another one small, one in front while the other one is behind). I wonder that how can I make 2 divs and make them have animation of up and down a little bit (like parrallax) like that when scroll up and down the site.

Thanks.

Comment: you will have to share necessary code to recreate the issue in the question itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the solutions I have seen to a problem like this involve JS of some kind and listen to the user's scroll event.

I have written a very simple example using JQuery. Here, the javascript listens for whenever a scroll happens, and measures how far the top of the page has been scrolled. Then it takes that value and multiplies it by different values for each image and uses `margin-top` to push the images down at different rates.

If the images were further down the page as in your example, I would suggest measuring from a different position than the top of the page. JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3Lb054qn/

Answer (score 0):

You have to change css position atributes according to scroll. So you have to do something like the following. In that margin-top is changed of second div tag.
Javascript code is as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).bind('scroll',function(e){
  var st = $(window).scrollTop();
  var cs = $(this).scrollTop();
  var wh = $( window ).height();
  var dv1 = $('#div1').offset().top;
  var dv2 = $('#div2').offset().top;

  var visible_dv1= dv1 - wh;
  //check wether div1 is in the viewport when scroll down
if(st > visible_dv1){
if(cs > lastScrollTop){
    //if scroll down
    $('#div2').css({
    'margin-top': "-=3"
  });
}else{
    //if scroll up
    $('#div2').css({
'margin-top': "+=3"
  });
}
}else{
    $('#div1').removeAttr('style');
    $('#div2').removeAttr('style');
}
  lastScrollTop = cs;
});
</script>
```

html and css would be something as follows.

```
<style>
.container{width:100%;}
.grid{font-size:22px; width:168px; height:168px; display:block; }
#div1{background:#C30;margin-top:1000px;float:none;position:relative;z-index:1000;}
#div2{background:#6C3;margin-top:-100px;margin-left:50px;float:none;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="grid" id="div1">
        div 1
    </div>
      <div class="grid" id="div2">
        div 2
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```